# How can I use map filters?

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuejs2

I need to use map filters because I have a lot of data and I need a map in CustomerID

This is my code:

```
computed: {

    customerMap() {
const map = {}
        this.customeritems.forEach(e => (map[e.CustomerID] = map[e.CustomerID] || []).push(e))
        return map
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map` returns a *new* array of your items, in your case you could write:

```
customerMap() {
const map = this.customeritems.map(e => (map[e.CustomerID] = map[e.CustomerID]))
   }
```

Since you do not have `{}` in the `.map` function then implicitly it returns a new array with the transformation done to it.
If you need to `filter` meaning only return a new array that fulfils a certain requirement then use the `.filter` method.